# sqlite locking issue on windows NTFS

Tags: windows, sqlite, locking, ntfs

The sqlite3.7 is giving this issue specifically for windows box on NTFS file system . it works fine on Ubuntu. I see there are many post regarding this but none of them gives a clear answer.
Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: Database.locked is coming on windows machine for sqlite ( NTFS drive) . Is there some issue there , how to fix it or workaround for it. The same code is working fine on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use SQLite when using multithreaded access to DB.

The locking in Sqlite is directly lockinbg Database and not granular like locking table or even more fine-grained at row level like most of the other DBMS server.